# Converting .pkl file to .csv file

Tags: python, export-to-csv, pickle

I am working on a python file that requires large data but I am not able to edit my data. Can someone suggest me a code on how can I convert a .pkl file to .csv file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. your question is lacking. im going to assume that by pkl you mean a python pickle file, which can contain just about anything, what does the data in it look like? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes it is a python pickle file. It is an emotion recording file in 10 persons.

Comment: yes but what does it look like? is its a list of something? is its a dictionary of something? is it an assortment of different data types?

Comment: It is a list containing string data type

Comment: each string is a correctly formatted csv line?, could you add an example of such a string to your question?

Answer (score 9):

Simplest and easy way to convert PKL file to csv

```
import pickle as pkl
import pandas as pd
with open("file.pkl", "rb") as f:
    object = pkl.load(f)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(object)
df.to_csv(r'file.csv')
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found a similar question here:

[How can I pickle a python object into a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48456900/how-can-i-pickle-a-python-object-into-a-csv-file)

You need this example from there:

```
import base64, csv
with open('a.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8') as csv_file:
    wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='|')
    pickle_bytes = pickle.dumps(obj)            # unsafe to write
    b64_bytes = base64.b64encode(pickle_bytes)  # safe to write but still bytes
    b64_str = b64_bytes.decode('utf8')          # safe and in utf8
    wr.writerow(['col1', 'col2', b64_str])
```

I modify it to read from your pickle file:

```
import pickle        
import base64
import csv

your_pickle_obj = pickle.loads(open('data.pkl', 'rb').read())
with open('output.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8') as csv_file:
    wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='|')
    pickle_bytes = pickle.dumps(your_pickle_obj)            # unsafe to write
    b64_bytes = base64.b64encode(pickle_bytes)  # safe to write but still bytes
    b64_str = b64_bytes.decode('utf8')          # safe and in utf8
    wr.writerow(['col1', 'col2', b64_str])
```

Comment: this is the wrong way, he wants to turn a pickle into a csv, not a csv into a pickle

Comment: It is from pickle to csv :)

Comment: But ok, I edit this example to load the pickle file itself too.

Comment: Could you upload somewhere the pkl file to test it?

Comment: I have searched on the google a little bit about this error message. Maybe it is an encoding problem. Some people wrote a solution which worked for them. They used pickle.loads indstead of pickle.load, so try it please:

    your_pickle_obj = pickle.loads(open('data.pkl', 'rb').read())

Comment: after writing pickle.loads, it shows error as -- "a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'". please help