# Efficient way to store SKLearn Birch model in Snowflake (and bypass 8MB binary limit)

Tags: python, serialization, scikit-learn, pickle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

my code is exactly that on the answer by @SimonD in this post [Store and retrieve pickled python objects to/from snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984593/store-and-retrieve-pickled-python-objects-to-from-snowflake/63986141?noredirect=1#comment113166472_63986141).  However I am now running into an error

> Programming Error: 100145 (22000): Binary value '800.....' is too long and would be truncated.

The object I am trying to persist is a clustering model (Birch) from skLearn. I am wondering if there is a better method for storing sklearn models in snowflake.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to bypass the 8MB limit in Snowflake but perhaps you could use a compression library before writing the pickled object to Snowflake? How big is your pickled model?

Comment: I would question why you are trying to store this binary data in Snowflake, which is an analytical db? Presumably you aren't running analytical queries against this data in Snowflake?

Comment: @SimonD.  It is 10.3MB (based on pickle.dumps(mod)), with .hex() it is 20.6MB.

Comment: @user1420372 What happens when you compress it? what size does it go down to? you can just use gzip or something to check.

Comment: @NickW.  You could be right, maybe not a good idea.  I am coming from SQL Server and had previously reviewed this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/python-taxi-classification-deploy-model?view=sql-server-ver15  and liked the idea to tie all together, with tables for 1) model versions (incl. json string of features, train date, etc), 2) predictions (linking back to model version) 3) evaluation metrics, etc. Moving into AWS world so need to review recommended methods for deployment, storage, etc (and set up S3 buckets..).  Snowflake meant I could defer!

Comment: Storing the model binary directly in S3 sounds like a much better idea. If you want to hold metadata about the binary in Snowflake then you could create a csv file (containing the metadata) alongside the binary and expose that as an external table in Snowflake. If you have multiple binaries/versions/etc you could potentially have metadata in the S3 file path (created date, version number, etc.) and have a Snowflake partitioned external table that will expose this metadata